# Cocktail etymology

Tags: word-usage, etymology

I was told that the word cocktail, when it was invented, was created from the union of two words, namely "cock" and "tail". I tried to check this claim using google, but was not able to come to any conclusion. Does this origin of the word sounds plausible?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the etymology of the word is uncertain. An excellent breakdown may be found in the Wikipedia article at the website sourced below. The following quote is taken from it:

*Etymologist Anatoly Liberman endorses as "highly probable" the theory advanced by Låftman (1946), which Liberman summarizes as follows:[7]
    It was customary to dock the tails of horses that were not thoroughbred ... They were called cocktailed horses, later simply cocktails. By extension, the word cocktail was applied to a vulgar, ill-bred person raised above his station, assuming the position of a gentleman but deficient in gentlemanly breeding. ... Of importance [in the 1806 citation above] is ... the mention of water as an ingredient. ... Låftman concluded that cocktail was an acceptable alcoholic drink, but diluted, not a "purebred", a thing "raised above its station". Hence the highly appropriate slang word used earlier about inferior horses and sham gentlemen.*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail